# Choosing schedule for courses

Tags: combinatorics

To fulfill the requirements for a certain degree, a student can choose to take any 8 out
of a list of 20 courses, with the constraint that at least 1 of the 8 courses must be a statistics course.Suppose that 5 of the 20 courses are statistics courses.

Why is the answer not (5 choose 1)(19 choose 7)?

Comment: Why 19 ? ${}{}$

Comment: The problem states $at \ least \ 1$ statistics course. So you have to consider the cases where the student chooses $2, 3, 4, 5$ statistics courses also.

Comment: But it's 19 choose 7, so wouldn't that also include the statistics classes he didn't choose?

Comment: Ok, in that case you are overcounting. For example:  
$$S_1; N_1, N_2,..., N_6, S_2$$
and  
$$S_2; N_1, N_2,..., N_6, S_1$$  
where $S_i$ denotes a statistics course and $N_i$ denotes a non statistics course. Can you see how you are counting the same case twice?

Comment: yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for the solution:  How many courses can the student take with no restriction?  How many courses can the student take if the student cannot take any statistics courses?  How do these two answers yield the answer to your problem?

What is wrong with your approach:  You are overcounting when the student takes multiple statistics courses.

Consider the simpler case of 4 courses, 2 stats (called A and B) and 2 not (called C and D).  The student must take at least one stats course.  Here, the student has five options, {AB, AC, AD, BC, BD}.  Your approach would give ${2 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1} = 6$.  That number counts the pairs (X,Y) where X is a stats course and Y is any course.  Thus you get the pairs (A,B), (A,C), (A,D), (B,A), (B,C), (B,D).  See what happened?  The course load of {A,B} was counted twice as (A,B) and as (B,A).  Similarly, multiple counting of the same schedule is happening in your problem.